# Eclipse-style tabbed pane -- "Show List" button when too many tabs

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a Swing application where the user can dynamically add tabs to a tabbed pane. We are running into the problem where the user adds so many tabs that they don't all fit on one line. I know that there are two options for the tab layout policy (and the scrolling policy may ultimately be sufficient), but I'm curious if there's a way to replicate the Eclipse "Show List" button in Swing. That is, if you are using the Eclipse IDE and you open, say, too many Java files at once, the tabbed pane will add a button to the right of the rightmost tab that you click to show a set of "hidden" tabs, i.e. the tabs that don't fit. Is this possible?

Thanks,

David

Comment: This is not possible with the standard UI. You could always try writing your own UI, but that would be a lot of work (I would think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time I've had a duplicate answer to two different questions.

You would have to write your own version of the [BasicTabbedPaneUI](http://fuseyism.com/classpath/doc/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicTabbedPaneUI-source.html) class, your own version of [JTabbedPane](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/swing/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.java.htm), and your own version of several other classes to reference your new classes.  Have fun.

Comment: Thanks! I guess for the time being we will go with the scrolling tab policy. If I ever do decide to create a new UI, I will try to post the results here.