# Java Swing: How to add pulldown menu to Tabbed pane

Tags: java, swing

I would like to extend the default Swing tab pane with a button that is right-aligned to the right border and on the same line as the tabs, where pushing the button would show a pulldown menu listing all open tabs.

Editors like Eclipse, Netbeans, Jira, etc. all have this feature giving the user a quick way to get a list of all open tabs and selecting one to view.

But regular Swing JTabbedPane doesn't seem to be extendable this way?

Andy ideas or suggestions for frameworks that implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Conceptually, the look and feel delegate would be the place to start, it's generally responsible for generating the layout (and painting) the tabs

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8607041/4857909) helps... Or maybe it will just scare you off from that topic :P - Good luck...

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. I'll look into extending the JTabbedPane with custom code to do what I would like it to do.